# ValueError: ssd_inception_v3 is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am getting this error while running bellow in colab

```
!python model_main.py --model_dir=training --pipeline_config_path=ssd_inception_v3.config
```

I am trying to do object detection. so for that I am using models from https://github.com/tensorflow/models , model is inception_v3 and config file is ssd_inception_v3.config

I am new for doing object detection using tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=training --pipeline_config_path=ssd_inception_v3.config
```

instead of `!python model_main.py`